# Help me with understanding the context

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, nuance

I'm having difficult time to understand the dialogue below.
It comes from "Project Runway season 19."

KRISTINA: Did you start to put your zippers?

CHASITY: It's not gonna be the last moment.  That's gonna be different this time 'cause it's gon' be the first moment before the last moment, you know what I'm saying?

What is Chasity trying to say here?
I know she is kind of slow at stitching or something during the challenges.
And here she has a lot of things to finish before the finale.

But I don't get clearly what she's saying here.
Would you please help me with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Chasity is being ironic. In essence, she's saying she's not going to wait till the last moment to put the zippers on (as she apparently did last time). Instead, she's going to do it the moment before that.